# What is best way to search a text to determine if it contains the word (or words) I am searching for?

Tags: php, string, substring

If it was just searching for a single word, it would have been easy, but the needle can be a word or more than a word.

```
Example
 $text = "Dude,I am going to watch a movie, maybe 2c Rio 3D or Water for Elephants, wanna come over";
 $words_eg1 = array ('rio 3d', 'fast five', 'sould surfer');
 $words_eg2 = array ('rio', 'fast five', 'sould surfer');
 $words_eg3 = array ('Water for Elephants', 'fast five', 'sould surfer');

'
 is_words_in_text ($words_eq1, $text)   / true, 'Rio 3D' matches with 'rio 3d'
 is_words_in_text ($words_eq2, $text)   //true, 'Rio' matches with 'rio'
 is_words_in_text ($words_eq3, $text)   //true, 'Water for Elephants'
```

Thank you,

Comment: have you considered strpos: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php, check the examples below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way to find the occurrence of a string in another string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821483/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-find-the-occurrence-of-a-string-in-another-string)

Comment: I am voting to close, but this question is a little different since it deals with case insensitive strings and word boundaries - you decide.

Answer (score 3):

In your case `stripos()` will probably do the trick:

```
function is_words_in_text($words, $string)
{
    foreach ((array) $words as $word)
    {
        if (stripos($string, $word) !== false)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

But this will match also non-words (as in `te` in `Water`), to fix this we can use `preg_match()`:

```
function is_words_in_text($words, $string)
{
    foreach ((array) $words as $word)
    {
        if (preg_match('~\b' . preg_quote($word, '~') . '\b~i', $string) > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

All searches are done in a case-insensitive way, `$words` can either be a string or an array.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the elements of $words_eg1, 2, 3 and stop as soon as `strpos` or `strstr` returns a non-false value.