# Can I filter an $_GET array in a foreach loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, foreach, get

I have a form on an internal database that isn't used or accessed by the public.

The form has a list of items generated from an SQL Database.
Each item has a check box to select if you want to carry it over the the next page.
It is never a set number of items and depends on which customer/table is being accessed.
The checkbox names are generated within an SQL select while loop so the checkbox name value goes up "num1,  num2, num3" etc.

On the form output I have:

```
foreach ($_get as $result){
echo $result;
}
```

This echoes the values of the full %_get array.

I want to filter it down to only show $_get values that contain "num" so it doesn't loop for anything else that may be in the $_get array.

So for example I want it to:

```
echo %_get['num1];
echo %_get['num2];
echo %_get['num3];
/* etc.. looping the amount of times the string "num" is used and not looping if for
example it didn't contain "num" like %_get['egg'] if it existed */
```

I hope this makes sense.

I'm open to any solutions or alternative ways of doing this if there is a better way.

Many Thanks,
Ash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foreach loop can select the key and value of the $_GET array items, so you can check if the key starts with *num*.

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if(strpos($key, 'num') === 0) {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

I highly recommend to filter and validate any input (GET, POST etc) especially on a production system. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php for starters.

Comment: This is perfect for what I was looking to do.
Thanks for the additional info on input validation too :)

Comment: Just to point out this code won't work as it stands, note the `$key` and `$_key`... its a trap!

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want to do something like this:

```
foreach($_GET as $key=>$val){
    if(false !== stripos($key, 'num')){
        echo $_GET[$key];
    }
}
```

This is looping over the full _GET array and checking if the key contains the string num. I have used the case insensitive stripos, if you want it to be case sensitive then replace `stripos` with `strpos`.

The reason for checking for explicit false is that stripos returns the string position which can be zero if the string is found. Zero in PHP is loosely equal to false. By using the `!==` instead of `!=` we are only matching on the result if it is not actual false (i.e not found at all).

Please note you really do need to do some kind of input filtering and output escaping on your real world code.

Comment: Checking for 0 is absolutely fine, since 0 means the needle was found at the start of the haystack. ;)

Comment: Exactly, hence checking to make sure it is not false but zero would be allowed with this code

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
foreach ($_GET as $key=>$result){
   if(substr($key, 0, 3) == 'num') {
     echo $result;
   }
}
```

loops all the $_GET global array and filters only those starting with 'num' and echoes the values.

Comment: You should give more than just a code dumb, explain the code

Comment: I agree with Patrick. Also strpos is a much faster way of checking if a string starts with another string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821483/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-find-the-occurrence-of-a-string-in-another-string

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_filter with a callback to filter out items of the array.

```
http://uk3.php.net/array_filter
```

for example:

```
function even($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is even
    return(!($var & 1));
}

$array = array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

print_r(array_filter($array, "even"));

$filteredArray = array_filter($array, "even");
```

This will filter out based on odd/even. you can change your callback to suite.

Comment: This is an overkill solution for what the OP requested. KISS, please.