# multiple explode and foreach, while searching a `input` value in txt file html/php/ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Actaully I have to search a `input` value from a `txt` file, when `keydown event` is triggered (it means the search function take place as `alphabetically`). That `txt` file has multiple lines and `keys`.

Now firstly let me describe the whole scenario with appropriate code.

HTML Code:

```
    <input type="text" name="searchval" /> 
    <div></div>

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('input').bind('keydown',function(){
        setTimeout(search($(this).val().toLowerCase()),2000);
      });
    });

    function search(v){
      $.ajax({
        url:'search.php',
        type:'get',
        data:'sv='+v,
        dataType:'json',
        cache:false,
        success:function(r){$('div').empty();for(var i in r){$('div').append(r[i]+",");}},
        error:function(a,b,c){$('body').append(b+'<hr/>');}
      });
    }
```

PHP Code:

```
  //ADD DATA TO TXT FILE
  $file = "UL.txt";
  if((!file_exists($file)) || (0 == filesize($file))){
    $data = "$name|$email|Offline";
  }else{
    $data = "\r\n$name|$email|Offline";
  }
  $fp = fopen("UL.txt", "a") or die("Couldn't open file for writing!");
  fwrite($fp, $data) or die("Couldn't write values to file!"); 
  fclose($fp);
```

`UL.txt'

```
  Abc Def|abc@def.com|Offline
  Ghi Jkl|ghi@jkl.com|Offline
  Mno Pqr|mno@pqr.com|Offline
  Stu Vwxyz|stuv@wxyz.com|Offline
  ....
```

`search.php`:

```
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $search = array();
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET"){
      $searchMe = $_GET['sv'];
      $F = file("UL.txt");
      foreach($F as $k1 => $v1) { 
        $d1[$k1] = explode("|", $v1);
        $email[] = strtolower(trim($d1[$k1][1])); //$d1[$k1][1];
        $name[] = strtolower(trim($d1[$k1][0])); //$d1[$k1][0];
        foreach($email as $k2 => $v2){
          if($v2 == $searchMe){
            $search[] = $v2; 
          }else{
            $search = 'NO RESULT';
          }
        }
      }
    }
    echo json_encode($search);
```

Now, this code doesn't work.

Instead of `$v2`, `$search[]` must return the `name:email:status` IF `$searchMe` matchs `$email` or `$name`, but I don't know how to do this. Means how to match `words by words` and use the `keys` to assign the whole line to the `$search[]`.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: Any errors at FF console?

Comment: @DushyantJoshi : No. In console response, I get `[]`

Comment: your $email doesn't seem to be returning an array. it is just giving email in search.php

Comment: so why are you using foreach for $email then?

Comment: And v2 should be $v2 in if()

Comment: @DushyantJoshi : Now `$email` and `$name` returning an `array`. : `$email[] = ` , `$name[] = `.

Comment: @DushyantJoshi : `typo mistake` :)
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to search between the exploded string (name, and email) why not use `stripos()`?

Sample code:

```
<?php

$data = array();
$return_value = array();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
    $needle = strtolower(urlencode($_GET['sv']));
    $file_contents = file('ul.txt');
    sort($file_contents);
    $range = strlen($needle);

    foreach($file_contents as $key => $haystack) {
        $smaller_haystack = explode('|', $haystack);
        // search for name or email
        $remove_dot_com = str_replace('.com', '', $smaller_haystack[1]);
        // if(stripos($smaller_haystack[0], $needle) !== false || stripos($remove_dot_com, $needle) !== false) {
       if((substr(strtolower($smaller_haystack[0]), 0, $range)) == $needle || (substr($remove_dot_com, 0, $range)) == $needle) {
            $return_value[$key]['name'] = $smaller_haystack[0];
            $return_value[$key]['email'] = $smaller_haystack[1];
            $return_value[$key]['status'] = $smaller_haystack[2];
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($return_value);
}

?>
```

and then just append results on html:

```
Search: <input type="text" name="search" id="search_field" />
<table id="search_results"></table>

$('#search_field').keyup(function(e){
    var search_value = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'results.php?sv=' + encodeURIComponent(search_value),
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
        $('#search_results').empty();
            $.each(response, function(index, element){
                $('#search_results').append('<tr><td>'+element.name+' - ' + element.email + ' - ' + element.status + '</td></tr>');
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks Dear, its words perfectly. But I want to know one thing, that `stripos()` is reliable or not, if `txt` file has thousands of line?

Comment: with regards to performance (statistical data), i cannot provide one, but you can also search for benchmarks on google or you can also check this one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821483/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-find-the-occurrence-of-a-string-in-another-string).

Comment: One more thing, It return all matching values, like, if i'm searching for `de`, than it returns all values that contains `de`. But at this scenario, it should match and returns `key line` based on the `starting alphabets` only.

Comment: if you want to only check the starting alphabet you can just change the condition to `substr()` instead of `stripos()`, check my edit

Comment: :) Its only works when `single alphabet` is entered. If `more than one` alphabets are entered, than :)

`, 0, 1`

Comment: i edited code so that it can dynamically accomodate more than one alphabet