# how to prevent form from submitting before and ajax request is sent

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

i have a form that on submit it will send an ajax request to another page to confirm if a username has already been used, but the form submits before the ajax even gets sent
"How am i sure of this" you may ask, ia m sure of this because the ajax request works fine when i call in from that console or when i change "onsubmit" to "onmouseover" i will add a snippet for those interested

```js
function validateform(){
 var rock = document.forms["myform"]["username"].value;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {var usercheck = new XMLHttpRequest();} 
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {var usercheck = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}  
    usercheck.open("POST", "../reciever.php", true);
usercheck.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
usercheck.send("user="+rock);
usercheck.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (usercheck.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    if(usercheck.responseText == "user"){
        alert('user exists');
    }
    //validate input if the username does not exists
  }
}; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<form class="login100-form validate-form flex-sb flex-w" name="myform" method="post" action="../../signup2/" onsubmit="return validateform(this);" id="form">
            <span class="txt1 p-b-11">
                        Fullname
                    </span>
                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-36" id="wrap1" data-validate = "Fullname is required">
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="fname" id="fulln" placeholder="Fullname">
    <br/>
                        <button class="login100-form-btn" name="reg" id="reg" onClick="return validateform();">
                            Signup
                        </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

i won't add my php because i am 100% sure that it works but my problem now is that the form does not validate(because the ajax does send in time before the form submits) i have tried adding 'return false;' immediately before my forms send(it works but now even if your credentials meet validation standards the form will never send)

Comment: `validateform` should return false to prevent the default form behavior

Comment: @user1597430 it works but now even if your credentials meet validation standards the form will never send no matter what

Comment: *"i won't add my php because i am 100% sure that it works"* - So why the php tag?

Comment: @user13782016 you should trigger submit event manually after the validation

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner sorry that was a mistake

Comment: @user1597430 how can i do that, when i tried $.(this).submit(function(e){e.preventdefault} which is jquery it still returned false