# Search php string - %like% sql

Tags: php, string, search

Right now I use `stristr($q, $string)` but if

```
$string = "one monkey can jump 66 times";
$q = "monkey 66";
```

I want to find out if this string contains both `monkey` and `66`.

How can i do that?

Comment: do you want to search similar words in both string ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(stristr('monkey', $string) && stristr('66', $string)) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Well, that don't work. I use ajax to send the variable from a text input. So if I want to know if the string contains both "monkey" and "66" i must explode $q first to an array.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Please be more explicit.

Comment: @AndersNilsson If you already know that you have to explode it, why do you ask?

Answer (score 2):

you could use both [stristr](https://www.php.net/manual/it/function.stristr.php) and [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

as it is reported in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820586/which-method-is-preferred-strstr-or-strpos), the second method is faster and less memory intensive.

well, check this lines out:

```
// here there are your string and your keywords
$string = "one monkey can jump 66 times";
$q = "monkey 66";

// initializate an array from keywords in $q
$q = explode(" ", $q);

// for every keyword you entered
foreach($q as $value) {

// if strpos finds the value on the string and return true
if (strpos($string, $value)) 

    // add the found value to a new array 
    $found[] = $value;

}

// if all the values are found and therefore added to the array,
// the new array should match the same object of the values array    
if ($found === $q) {

    // let's go through your path, super-man!
    echo "ok, all q values are in string var, you can continue...";

}
```

Comment: if ($found === $q) {

    // let's go through your path, super-man!
    echo "ok, all q values are in string var, you can continue...";

}
it's an array, you cant compare it to $q or?

Comment: $q is became an array when we exploded it: $q = explode(" ", $q); so the === checks if two objects are identical

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function which is used to find the occurrence of one string inside another one:

```
$a = 'How are you?';

if (strpos($a, 'are') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Note that the use of `!== false` is deliberate (neither `!= false` nor `=== true` will work); `strpos()` returns either the offset at which the needle string begins in the haystack string, or the boolean `false` if the needle isn't found. Since 0 is a valid offset and 0 is "falsey", we can't use simpler constructs like `!strpos($a, 'are')`.

Answer (score -1):

simply post your variable value by giving them a variable $monkey,$value ($monkey jumps $value) and then fetch its value

Comment: This is a very.. Very long process, functionality of the site would seriously drop due to the amount of inputs

Comment: no it can simply achieve it by ajax just post the value by given id and + (add)it by another value then simply post it via datastream